# switch between Two UIview Using setHidden in a containers

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uicollectionview, uicontainerview

i'm using a container with three UIView , i'm using storyBoard also and i set my first UIView with a catalogConainerView that contain a Collection  and my second is a catalogTableContainerView which contain a TableView (the 3rd one doesn't matter in this question), and i wanna be able to switch or to flip between the two containers (when i am on the collection view i wanna have a BarButtonItem that help me switch to the tableView display and when i am on collection view i'll have the same BarButtonItem with a different name help me to switch to the TableView and vice versa...
my code is the following:

`
- (void)switchDisplayMyType
{

```
if (self.isCollectionActive){


    [self.catalogContainerView setHidden:NO];

        BarButtonItem *displayButton = [[BarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"List" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(flipDisplayType)];

        [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:displayButton];


}else{

    [self.catalogContainerView setHidden:YES];
    [self.catalogTableContainerView setHidden:NO];

    BarButtonItem *displayButton = [[BarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Collection" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(flipDisplayType)];

       [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:displayButton];

}
```

}`

and i'm calling my function SwitchDisplayMyType on a viewDidLoad.
My code doesn't work, and i have two problems, even if i check on the storyBoard the setHidden property and i wanted the collectionView to be displayed first,i got the inverse, and the second problem is that, i don't know how to check in my function for myPreviousView and my currentView to test if i'm on a Collection or a TableView !!!
Can you help me PLZ

Comment: Show the code inside your method 'flipDisplayType'

Comment: the code above is the code inside my function flipDisplayType, it's just recursive! i replace the above `if(self.isColl..) by if (!self.isColl...)` and i add in the if `_isCollectionActive = YES;` but i only have a TablViewDisplay for both !!!

Comment: I think you created some mess you can't get out yourself anymore. Try having 1 method that switches the view's hidden state, might be easier to track down bugs

Comment: this is what i did! i creat one methods which switches view's Hidden!!! or do you mean something else!